# Boost::asio: data get received only after other connection appeared

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to use code examples in my application. At a connection client sends "hello!" to the server. Server receives it and answers on it somehow (and ends message with "Hi, client! I'm server!") - but that's what i have: server doesn't receive anything until I connect to it by telnet and send something. After that it receives (prints) both clients and telnet messages.

Client:

```
socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 21), error);
if (error)
  throw boost::system::system_error(error);
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Hello!\n"), boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
for (;;)
{
  boost::array<char, 128> buf;
  boost::system::error_code error;

  size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

  if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
    break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
  else if (error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

  std::cout.write(buf.data(), len);
}
```

server:

```
for (;;)
{
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);
    for (;;)
    {
        boost::array<char, 128> buf;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

        if (buf[len-1] == '/n')
            break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
        else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
        std::string a(buf.data());
    }

    std::string message = make_daytime_string();
    boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("Hi, client! I'm server!"),
    boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);
}
```

I'm afraid I forgot something to close (like socket). But anyway - and ideas?

Comment: Your writes back are commented out, but even so the server will not attempt to execute the write until after the client has disconnected because of the `for(;;)` that is only broken when an error reading is received.  What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: In your server setup an `acceptor` that will accept a single connection.  Once that connection is established, your server will read from the connected application using the `read_some()` function until that connection is closed.  Once that connection is closed the server attempts to write data back to the client using `write()`.  Only then will the server accept additional connections.  These seems like it doesn't match what your description of the expected behavior was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

if (buf[len-1] == '/n')
```

you've made some assumptions about `tcp::ip::socket::read_some()` that are [not true](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html).

> *Remarks*
>
> The read_some operation may not read all of the requested number of
>   bytes. Consider using the [read function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the blocking operation
>   completes.

I suggest you use the `read()` [free function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) as the documentation suggests.